# PHP function not returning the right values

Tags: php, sql, ms-access-2010

```php
function ship($orderid)
{
    $shipping = 0;
    $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};Dbq=Database3.mdb", "", "");
    $sql = "Select * From pay WHERE order_id=" . $orderid . " AND Field3='Shipping Services'";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $shipping = $row["Field21"];
    }

    return $shipping;
}
```

The ship function returns the cost of shipping but it doesn't work.
The table contains the order field3 which contains 3 type of transaction: Shipping Services, Refund and Order. The table also contains one field order id and one field name cost.

I need cost if `field==Shipping Services` for specific order id.

Comment: You should add details about data in your database and the error you get.

Comment: what problem you are facing? your tables data screen-shot and what your expected outcome?

Comment: If you only need `Field21` then just query for that field, don't retrieve all fields. If you are not expecting more than one row there is no need for the `while` loop. You could even add the `LIMIT 1` option in your query. If you expect more rows be sure to add them up in the `while` loop. Do you assign the result to a variable, otherwise you have to `echo` it to see it.

Comment: table contain orders field3 contain 3 type of transaction  Shipping Services
,Refund,Order and one field order id that contain order_id and one field name cost. i need cost if field==Shipping Services for specific oreder id

Comment: If your code "doesn't work" then you will need to "fix it". If you cannot be more specific then neither can we. See [ask].